# What can I use as default value for a datetime form element?

Tags: 8, forms, datetime

I need to create a custom contact form in Drupal 8. I wrote all the code to build the form. I just need to set the default value for a *datetime* form element.

The code I am using to add that form element is the following one.

```php
$form['start_date'] = [
  '#type' => 'datetime',
  '#title' => t('Start date'),
  '#default_value' => time(),
];
```

The value I am using for the default value doesn't show the expected value. What should I use instead of `time()`?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

use Drupal\Core\Datetime\DrupalDateTime;

and in form

```
$form['start_date'] = array(
  '#type' => 'datetime',
  '#title' => t('Start Date'),
  '#default_value' => DrupalDateTime::createFromTimestamp(time()),
);
```

Comment: just new DrupalDateTime() also defaults to the currrent time.

Comment: But for the value, use: `'#value' => DrupalDateTime()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')`

Answer (score 5):

The `#default_value` datetime field element expects a [`DrupalDateTime`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Datetime!DrupalDateTime.php/class/DrupalDateTime/8.2.x) object, not a date string.

```
use Drupal\Core\Datetime\DrupalDateTime;

$form['start_date'] = [
       '#type' => 'datetime',
       '#title' => t('Start Date'),
       '#description' => date($date_format, time()),
       '#default_value' => new DrupalDateTime('1978-11-01 10:30:00', 'Europe/Berlin'),
     ];
```

For more information see [`Datetime::processDatetime()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Datetime%21Element%21Datetime.php/function/Datetime%3A%3AprocessDatetime/8.2.x) & [`Datetime`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Datetime%21Element%21Datetime.php/class/Datetime/8.2.x) in the API docs.

Comment: The code is using the wrong value for *#description*.

Answer (score 2):

Also using Drupal 8.  This [discussion](https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/module-development-and-code-questions/2016-08-26/drupal-8-date-element) raises an important point - ensure that your date format matches.

I wanted to display the date as d/m/Y but that is not the default format used by the date field:

```
$today = date("Y-m-d");
$form['general']['endDate'] = ['#type' => 'date','#date_format' => 'd/m/Y','#title' => t('End date'),'#default_value' => $today,];
```

The clue was in the generated HTML:

```
data-drupal-date-format="Y-m-d"
```

The discussion states that the default could be changed but I did not validate that proposition.

Answer (score 0):

For Drupal 8, the following piece of code works:

// Form element inside buildForm().

```
$form['start_date'] = [
      '#type' => 'datetime',
      '#title' => t('Start Date'),
      '#default_value' => DrupalDateTime::createFromTimestamp(strtotime($config->get('start_date')))
    ];
```

// Inside submitForm().

```
->set('start_date', (string) $form_state->getValue('start_date'))
```